# Disable SSH key authentification for one user

Tags: git, unix, ssh, sshd

For now, I use key authentification for all my server users and it worked very well. Today I've just added a git service which job is to serve git repository for everyone : internal users of my server and external.

I've created a Git user for all the git purpose (daemon, cgit, etc...) 
The problem is that when people want to clone one of my repository, because of the sshd_config, the server check the ~/.ssh/authorized_key file and I just know that it's unthinkable to stock all the public key of foreign users in this file.

So, is there a way to specify that only the Git user of my server has the right to connect without any key authentification and password ?

In advance, I apologize for my English.
Thanks,

Comment: But won't you still need to identify yourself as the git user? How would the server verify that you're that user without the keys? Perhaps what you're wanting is no-authentication access to a host.

Comment: No I don't need the server to verify that I'm the real git user. It's because I use a another user which is my personnal user in this server. What I want is a no-authentification access only for the git user in order to allow anyone the pull and push code in my public repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't try it right now (no linux maschine) but this at the end of your `sshd_config` should allow password login for the git user only

```
Match user git
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

see [the man pages](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd%5fconfig). If you want to allow password access for a git group you can replace user with group.

If you add

```
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

to the Match group you can login as git without password.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the password identification but despite the "PermitEmptyPasswords yes", the server ask me for one. Any ideas ?

Comment: Does the user git have a passwort? If yes ssh will ask for it. You can delete it with passwd -d git

Comment: I did it before you answer me and it worked well ! Thanks for your help :)